# Creating an LDAP script to edit active directory

Tags: active-directory, email, ldap

When setting up a new email, the user is directed to a blank address list (so they cannot access other users email addresses). This is done manually using ADSIedit.

However, there are a lot of new emails to set up.  How can I create an LDAP script for exchange server (to edit active directory)?

Comment: What's the purpose? Why do you want them to have a blank address list?

Comment: @joeqwerty: yes they should have a blank address list.  Basically hundreds of new addresses need to be added every year, and the new addresses should have blank address lists.

Comment: I'm not understanding why they need blank address lists? Can you explain that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As Christian said, Perl-LDAP can help, but I think that if you're using AD (rather than OpenLDAP) and are running Windows, Powershell or VBScript are going to save you the steps of needing to explicitly bind to LDAP.

The [Script Center Repository](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/en-us) will have a lot of examples, and the [Microsoft Technet Script Center](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/scriptcenter/) has loads of articles and tuturoials

Answer (score 0):

[Perl-Ldap](http://ldap.perl.org/) can help you. There are a lot of good examples, so it is easy to start.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be binding to ActiveDirectory, then the DirectoryServices library included with .NET has a very nice object known as a DirectoryEntry for handling users and other AD objects. It is more AD-centric than LDAP-centric (although it does use the AD-LDAP syntax) and it's just what you are looking for. You can use C#, VB.NET or any of the other .NET-aware languages to write a nice tool that will add the mail entries for you. With AD I would definitely look to use a .NET-based solution rather than more traditional Unix-style LDAP tools. There is quite a bit of good documentation out there via your favorite search engine regarding the use of DirectoryEntry for type of thing you are trying to do.